# How can I get my mother to give me a copy of her will?

Tags: united-states, family, money

When my father died my sisters went to his home and met with his attorney without me.

I did not see his will. My dad was wealthy,

I received $2000 from my dad's bank, and I don't know what my sisters received. They cut me out of their lives after he died.

My thoughts (and fear) is that the $2000 were not a fair share and that my  sisters took some sort of advantage.

My mom knows everything that happened with my sisters and my dad's will. She doesn't give me any insight into it.

After that experience, I've tried telling her that it would be good to have someone know her wishes. When I talk to her about it she turns away and will not address me. She goes silent. She won't even tell me who her executor is. My mom is 82.

Comment: Would not the father's attorney be the right party to address instead of the mother?

Comment: Have a look at https://www.legalzoom.com/articles/how-to-get-a-copy-of-a-will

Comment: @BurninLeo That's a good idea, I will see if I can find out who his attorney was. I know who my mom's attorney is. She would flip her lid if I went to him for a copy of her will. I love that idea though, thanks so much!

Comment: Probably not a question for IS. Maybe you could try Legal?

Comment: Your mom's will is her confidential business and her attorney would not give you any information about it.

Comment: Could you focus on enjoying her company while she is alive? / If she has a will, either it will be found after she died, or it won't; if it isn't found, then she will be assumed to have died intestate.

Comment: @RedSonja: Might be worth posting on Legal, but they'll probably tell you some variation of "Get a lawyer, and by the way, here are some things you might want to discuss with said lawyer." I imagine that "some things" would be various details about how the probate process works in OP's state (if OP would provide a state), the statute of limitations, and whether or not OP could plausibly have a conversion case against the sisters or other heirs.

Comment: Sounds like your mom might be up to some similar shenanigans with her estate and is in cahoots with your sisters. Just expect nothing for an inheritance and enjoy the remaining years you have with her. She clearly doesn't want to talk about this with you and she truly has no obligation to do so... it's her money and she can do whatever she wants with it.